# combine 2 view into 1 view

Tags: drupal-6, view

Is there a way to "merge" 2 different views into one view? 
i need to control how many of each content type are displayed

Answer (score 0):

Just use the panels module. With panels you can define a page with different regions (you'll probably need two of these). The content of such a region may even be a view and you are able to restrict the shown entries of each view through the panel ui.

http://drupal.org/project/panels

Answer (score 0):

You could create the second view as an attachment to the first view. This is likely the easiest way to go about it. The attached view can inherit any arguments used in the first view as well.